# not able to run rake db:create in windows to install fedena

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, cmd, fedena

getting error on running cmd in windows Please help me what to do: here is rake

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for
example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to 
Rake.
require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'tasks/rails'
```

and here is the cmd window

```
c:\Fedena>rake db:create --trace
(in c:/Fedena)
rake aborted!
c:/Fedena/Rakefile:3: syntax error, unexpected kAND
...lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be av...
                              ^
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:23
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this part be commented out?

```
    # Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for
#example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to 
#Rake.


require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))


require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'tasks/rails'
```

Looks like it's not commented out and ruby is trying to run it as code

Comment: I have try to comment out this too but it still not working

Comment: I dont know which file it is instructing to automatically available

Comment: please copy and paste your entire rakefile.rake

Comment: # Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for
#example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to 
#Rake.


require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))


require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'tasks/rails'

Answer (score 0):

My installation is successful. Below is my rake file content:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'

require 'tasks/rails'
```

Copy and paste the above content in your rake file and try again